# GIT back to an older version

Tags: git

I have 2 branches on my `git` repository (Master and Version1). Currently I am working on the branch Version1 (several files). Now i want to get back to an older Versions (`0780033` --> several commits before) - all files should be changed to that version; but i don't want to delete the previous - i just want to "copy" this old version and paste it, so that the copy of `0780033` is my actual version. I am not sure if I should use reset, or checkout or revert?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you should checkout to SHA-1 which you want with command:

`git checkout -b old_version <SHA-1>`

or with command if you already have created branch:

`git checkout <branch_name>`

By usage of this commands some files can be modified, additional files which was added in newer version and were untracked shall stay untracked. On opposite additional files which were added in newer version and commited shall disappear in older version.

Comment: Thank you, but was does SHA-1 mean? I have 2 branches - working on Version1 and in this branch i want to go back to an older versino (also in this branch). Lets say i have in branch Version1 the commits: C1, C2,C3(the latest) -->and i want back to C1. So the commits should be: C1,C2,C3,C4 why C4 Version is equal to C1

Comment: Every commit in git has some kind of unique identification number which is called `SHA-1 sum`. You can find this sum by typing command `git log --pretty=oneline` the long numbers on the left side would be `SHA-1 sums` for your commits.

Comment: I tried :git checkout 078003 but then i got the following message: You are in "detached head" state. You can look around...--> and then I am not in the Branch B1; --> but in branch ((0780033...)

Comment: Yes,  in order to create local branch type `git branch <branch_name>` and you are on your local branch which is based on commit `078003`